# Create XML from Access

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba

We need to generate an XML using Access, is there any Visual Basic objects or functions that can help with the task ?

Comment: What exactly do you need? An xml file or just a string? What's the purpose of generating xml?

Answer (score 1):

Try using XmlDocument type.

http://www.functionx.com/vbnet/xml/Lesson02.htm

There's also Chilkat XML ActiveX.

https://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatxml.asp

https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatXmlRef.html

Comment: @HackSlash Thanks, updated to original documentation

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Application.ExportXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193212%28v=office.15%29.aspx)? If you type "exportxml" into the help in the VBE, it will get you ExportXML method as the first choice.

Answer (score 0):

I found it much easier to build my own functions.  You can find the 3 functions [here](http://idevlop.blogspot.com/2009/09/generer-du-xml-depuis-vba.html).
The basic idea is to build a recorset (query), loop through it to build your string. 
See the comments.  The blog is in French but the code comments are in English.